# Laravel query using whereHas

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 models: car painted color, and cars

```
public function color()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Colors::class)->latest();
}
```

I need to search the latest painted car color but with whereHas, it's searching all colors

```
$colors = ['black', 'white'];
$cars->whereHas('color', function($cars) use ($colors) {
          return $cars->whereIn('paint_color', $colors);
});
```

How can I make whereIn to only query on the latest row?

Comment: Where did you use the get() method in the $cars variable?

Comment: I have many cars and many colors at the db, i use pagination `$cars->paginate(10)->appends(....);`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since each car could have been painted many colors but you want to retrieve the latest painted color. This means you have a one to many relationship from car to color. Therefore the relationship color should be changed to

```
public function colors()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Colors::class)
        ->latest();
}
```

Then to only retrieve the latest color you can call `->limit(1)` since the colors are already ordered by the relationship.

```
$cars = $query->with(['colors', function($query) {
        return $query->limit(1);
    }])
    ->get();
```

Then you can filter whether the latest color is in your `$colors` array

```
$filteredCars = $cars->filter(function($car) {
    return $car->colors->whereIn('paint_color', $colors);
});
```

Comment: I have many cars and many colors at the db, i use pagination `$cars->paginate(10)->appends(....);`
How i can remove unnecessary rows?

Comment: then I don't know, if you want to use paginate() you should use one query but my solution has to retrieve cars and color then filter it later.

Comment: maybe you can help me with any solutions?